# C# Visual Studio 2010 ultimate include html files in ClickOnce Deployment

Tags: c#, html, deployment, clickonce

I have a C# program created in VS 2010 ultimate. I have added .html files to be used as help files. The help files are in a directory in the same directory as the project file. Does anyone know what the path would be from current directory after deployment with ClickOnce? Nothing I have tried has worked. I have also put the .html files in the same directory as project file but that doesn't work either. (I have added the .html files in project properties)

Comment: I tried to give a tick to you all but wouldn't let me. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Solution Explorer, right click on your `x.html` file and select `Properties`. In the properties set `Copy to Output Directory` setting to `Copy always`.

In your code reference your x.html file using this code:

```
var directoryPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
var filePath = Path.Combine(directoryPath, "x.html");
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Setting the Copy to Output to Copy always worked. I also had to set Build Action to content

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the .HTML files to your project itself?  Then, inside the project set 'Copy To Output Directory' to `True`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Setting the Copy to Output to Copy always worked. I also had to set Build Action to content

Answer (score 0):

Go to the properties of the files and make sure `Copy to Output` is `true`. And then, you should be able to access them like this:

```
string path = string.Format(@"{0}\{1}", Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), @"Path\To\The\File.txt");
```